# How to adjust community border width in igraph in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am just wondering how the border width for the groups is adjusted in igraph in R. As shown below, I made an example graph with walktrap community detection, and would like to plot the graph with community borders, but I have no idea how to adjust the community border width (like the one for adjusting edge with: edge.width). I tried to find any information via igraph manual, but there is no information how to adjust the community border with other than the ones for community group shape or community expand options. Thank you in advance!

```
library(igraph)

# Generate random graph and community structure
set.seed(23)
g <- sample_gnm(15, 45)
wc <- walktrap.community(g)

# Plot
layout <-layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot(wc, g, layout=layout, vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.size=5, edge.arrow.size=.2,
     mark.shape=0, edge.width=0.1, mark.expand=10)
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable if the same width would be set to both the community and the vertex borders?

Comment: That would be an ad-hoc solution, but not the definite one that I would like to have.

Comment: What I said could be simply achieved with, e.g., `par(lwd = 3)` before plotting. Otherwise, there is no easy way. The chain of relevant functions called is `plot.communities` -> `plot.igraph` -> `igraph.polygon` -> `xspline`. As to achieve what you want, you would need to pass, say, `lwd = 3`to `xspline`. However, neither `xspline` nor `igraph.polygon` take any of additional parameters supplied to `plot`. So, the solution then would be to redefine some of those functions or to plot something manually.

Comment: Okay, it's more complicated than I would thought. Thanks any way!